# validated_data is returning empty OrderedDict for nested fields with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can someone help me figure out why some fields are not parsed correctly using nested serializers with Django and Django-rest-framework?

I've researched the issue on SO, and the only cause for this happening I've found is that the request is sent as Form-data and not Json, but I've checked that response.content_type equals application/json - so this shouldn't be the issue here.

This is what my validated_data looks like (note that 3 of the fields only contain an empty OrderedDict):

```
{'author': OrderedDict(),
 'disclosed_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 19, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>),
 'event_date': datetime.date(2021, 10, 20),
 'event_type': OrderedDict(),
 'subject_companies': [OrderedDict()]}
```

This is what request.data looks like (where you can see that all fields are there, and having the fields that each serializer have specified, provided below this paragraph):

```
{'event_type': {'pk': 1}, 'author': {'pk': 1}, 'event_date': '2021-10-20', 'disclosed_at': '2021-10-19 12:00:00', 'subject_companies': [{'pk': 1}]}
```

This is where I'm sending the request from (test.py):

```
  def test_authenticated_creating_event_for_own_organisation(self):
        view = NewsEventList.as_view()
        url = reverse('news_event_list', kwargs={'pk': self.organisation.pk})
        request = self.client.post(url, data=json.dumps(self.payload_event), content_type='application/json')
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
        response = view(request, pk=self.organisation.pk)
        
        json_data = json.dumps(response.data, indent=4)
        json_ = (json.loads(json_data))  

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201, 'Should return 201 - Created')
        return response
```

Models

```
class NewsEvent(TimeStampedModel):
    event_type = models.ForeignKey('publication.eventtype', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='events_type', null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('core.organisation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events_author', null=True)
    subject_companies = models.ManyToManyField('core.organisation',  related_name='events_companies')


    legacy_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    event_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    event_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    disclosed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.author, self.event_type) 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)


class EventType(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Language', 
        default=get_default_language, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='event_contents'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name) 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
```

The view

```
class NewsEventList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedAndOfSameOrganisationEvents,)
serializer_class = NewsEventSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    org_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
    try:
        org_obj = Organisation.objects.get(pk=org_pk)
    except Organisation.DoesNotExist:
        return ValidationError('Organisation does not exist')

    news_events = NewsEvent.objects.filter(author=org_obj)
    return news_events
```

Serializers

```
class OrganisationNameSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Organisation
        fields = ['pk']


class EventTypeSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EventType
        fields = ['pk']

class HeadlineSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EventHeadline
        fields = ['news_event', 'language', 'headline']

class NewsEventSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    event_type = EventTypeSerializer()
    author = OrganisationNameSerializer()
    subject_companies = OrganisationNameSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewsEvent
        fields = ['pk', 'event_type', 'author', 'event_date', 'event_time', 'disclosed_at', 'subject_companies', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # Get PK for organisation from URL
        org_pk = self.context.get('request').parser_context.get('kwargs', {}).get('pk', {})
        org_obj = Organisation.objects.get(pk=org_pk)

        print(self.context.get('request').data)
        pprint(validated_data)
```

Also for reference I printed the serializer.data for an already existing instance of a NewsEvent:

```
news_event_test = NewsEvent.objects.all()[0]
serializer = NewsEventSerializer(news_event_test)
print(serializer.data)
    
{'pk': 1, 'event_type': OrderedDict([('pk', 1)]), 'author': OrderedDict([('pk', 1)]), 'event_date': None, 'event_time': None, 'disclosed_at': None, 'subject_companies': [OrderedDict([('pk', 1)])], 'created_at': '2021-10-25T09:32:41.562428+02:00', 'updated_at': '2021-10-25T09:32:41.562487+02:00'}
```

I've also tried doing a "pop" of each of the fields from the validated_object, but only the ones that don't is an empty OrderedDict work, such as disclosed_at, but if I try to do:

```
event_type = validated_data.pop('event_type')
```

I get:

```
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `event_type` on serializer `NewsEventSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'event_type'."
```

Comment: can you add your view's code snippet?

Comment: I've added the view @Shaonsani

Comment: Also add models !

Comment: Added models @Shaonsani

Comment: just try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I was doing a write operation (POST request, create action in Django/DRF terms) and the pk field on the serializers is read_only by default.

To validate that data during write ops, you'll need to set the field explicitly and set read_only=False. For example:

```
class RedditTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Task
        fields = ("pk",)
```

This solved the problem, but you may want to consider using
PrimaryKeyRelatedField if your use case is only setting the primary key
of a related object.

Answer (score 0):

```
event_type = models.ForeignKey('publication.EventType', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='events_type', null=True)
author = models.ForeignKey('core.Organisation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events_author', null=True)
subject_companies = models.ManyToManyField('core.Organisation',  related_name='events_companies')
```

Replace those lines and delete previous migrations and create new ones and try.

Comment: Can't see that you made any adjustments?